# Log Normal Random Variables with Scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I fail to understand the very basics of creating lognormal variables as documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html).

[The log normal distribution takes on mean and variance as parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution). I would like to create a frozen distribution using these parameters and then get cdf, pdf etc.

However, in the documentation, they get the frozen distribution using

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
s = 0.953682269606
rv = lognorm(s)
```

's' seems to be the standard deviation. I tried to use the 'loc' and 'scale' parameters instead of 's', but that generated an error (s is a required parameter). How can I generate a frozen distribution with parameter values 'm', 's' for location and scale?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## The mystery is solved (edit 3)

- μ corresponds to `ln(scale)` (!)
- σ corresponds to shape (`s`)
- `loc` is not needed for setting any of σ and μ

I think it is a severe problem that this is not clearly documented. I guess many have fallen for this when doing simple tests with the lognormal distribution in SciPy.

## **Why is that?**

The stats module treats `loc` and `scale` the same for all distributions (this is not explicitly written down, but can be inferred when reading between the lines). My suspicion was that `loc` is substracted from `x`, and the result is divided by `scale` (and the result is treated as the new `x`). I tested for that, and this turned out to be the case.

What does it mean for the lognormal distribution? In the canonical definition of the lognormal distribution the term `ln(x)` appears. Obviously, the same term appears in SciPy's implementation. With above's considerations, this is how `loc` and `scale` end up **in** the logarithm:

```
ln((x-loc)/scale)
```

By common logarithm calculus, this is the same as

```
ln(x-loc) - ln(scale)
```

In the canonical definition of the lognormal distribution the term simply is  `ln(x) - μ`. Comparing SciPy's approach and the canonical approach then provides the crucial insight: **`ln(scale)` represents μ**. `loc`, however, has no correspondence in the canonical definition and is better left at 0. Further below, I have argued for the fact that shape (`s`) is σ.

## Proof

```
>>> import math
>>> from scipy.stats import lognorm
>>> mu = 2
>>> sigma = 2
>>> l = lognorm(s=sigma, loc=0, scale=math.exp(mu))
>>> print("mean: %.5f  stddev: %.5f" % (l.mean(), l.std()))
mean: 54.59815  stddev: 399.71719
```

I use WolframAlpha as a reference. It provides analytically determined values for the mean and standard deviation of the lognormal distribution.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log-normal+distribution%2C+mean%3D2%2C+sd%3D2

[image]

The values match.

WolframAlpha as well as SciPy come up with the mean and standard deviation by evaluating **analytical** terms. Let's perform an empirical test, by taking many samples from the SciPy distribution, and calculate their mean and standard deviation "manually" (from the whole set of samples):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> samples = l.rvs(size=2*10**7)
>>> print("mean: %.5f  stddev: %.5f" % (np.mean(samples), np.std(samples)))
mean: 54.52148  stddev: 380.14457
```

This is still not perfectly converged, but I think it is proof enough that the samples correspond to the same distribution that WolframAlpha assumed, given μ=2 and σ=2.

And another small edit: it looks like proper usage of a search engine would have helped, we were not the first to be trapped by this:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33036/fitting-log-normal-distribution-in-r-vs-scipy
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~jsteven5/blog/lognormal_distributions.ipynb
[scipy, lognormal distribution - parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747761/scipy-lognormal-distribution-parameters)

Another edit: now that I know how it behaves, I realize that be behavior in principle is documented. In [the "notes" section](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) we can read:

> with shape parameter sigma and scale parameter exp(mu)

It is just really not obvious (we both were not able to appreciate the importance of this small sentence). I guess the reason that we could not understand what this sentence means is that the analytical expression shown in the notes section does *not* include `loc` and `scale`. I guess this is worth a bug report / documentation improvement.

**Original answer:**

Indeed, the shape parameter topic is not well-documented when looking into the docs page for a particular distribution. I recommend having a look at the main stats documentation -- there is a section on shape parameters:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#shape-parameters

It looks like there should be a `lognorm.shapes` property, telling you about what the `s` parameter means, specifically.

**Edit:**
There is only one parameter, indeed:

```
>>> lognorm.shapes
's'
```

When comparing the general definition of the lognormal distribution (from Wikipedia):
[image]

and the formula given by the scipy docs:

```
lognorm.pdf(x, s) = 1 / (s*x*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-1/2*(log(x)/s)**2)
```

it becomes obvious that `s` is the true σ (`sigma`).

However, from the docs it is not obvious how the `loc` parameter is related to μ (`mu`).

It could be as in `ln(x-loc)`, which would *not* correspond to μ in the general formula, or it could be `ln(x)-loc`, which would ensure correspondence between `loc` and μ. Try it out! :)

**Edit 2**

I have made comparisons between what WolframAlpha (WA) and SciPy say. WA is pretty clear about that it uses μ and σ as generally understood (as defined in linked Wikipedia article).

```
>>> l = lognorm(s=2, loc=0)
>>> print("mean: %.5f  stddev: %.5f" % (l.mean(), l.std()))
mean: 7.38906  stddev: 54.09584
```

This matches [WA's output](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log-normal%20distribution%2C%20mean%3D0%2C%20sd%3D2).

Now, for `loc` not being zero, there is a mismatch. Example:

```
>>> l = lognorm(s=2, loc=1)
>>> print("mean: %.5f  stddev: %.5f" % (l.mean(), l.std()))
mean: 8.38906  stddev: 54.09584
```

WA [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log-normal%20distribution%2C%20mean%3D1%2C%20sd%3D2) a mean of 20.08 and a standard deviation of 147. There you have it, `loc` does **not** correspond to μ in the classical definition of the lognormal distribution.